# Как можно доставать value из checkbox в React?

Tags: reactjs

Я не знаю на сколько правильно мое решение, но оно вот

```
    let [check, setChecked] = useState([])
    const checkClick = (e) => {
        if(e.target.checked){
            setChecked([...check, e.target.value])
        } else {
            let w = e.target.value
            setChecked(check.filter((word) => word !== w))
            console.log(w)
        }


    }
```

Существует ли лучше?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267669/retrieving-value-of-checkbox-in-react-js - возможно это Вам поможет

Comment: Какое value вы хотите получить от чекбокса? Зачем эти value складываете в массив?

Comment: Кажется, проще и понятнее будет каждый раз брать `.value` у всех `.checked` элементов чекбокса.